# mysql previous/next id and cycle

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have set up my code to get the previous and next id. But once it hit the last or beginning of the numbers, it won't let me go next or previous, respectively.

This is how I set my sql query

```
$pre = mysql_query("SELECT iID,userID FROM images WHERE iID < # AND userID = 4 ORDER BY iID DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$nex = mysql_query("SELECT iID,userID FROM images WHERE iID > # AND userID = 4 ORDER BY iID ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Can someone help me cycle the query? So if it hits the lowest number, or the largest number, it will go back cycle

ex:

```
iID     userID

3        4
4        0
5        4
10       4
```

So if I cycle through all the userID with 4 and currently it will show iID, 5, I can click previous and next and it will then go to iID 3 and 10, respectively. But when it hits 3 or 10, it is the max. I would like to continue through the query. So if I hit previous, it will go 3, and if I hit previous again, it will go to 10, and then 5, and then 3, then back to 10...

Can someone help me?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the min and max iID's you have a range you can check from

UPDATE (this should return two values min/max):

```
SELECT MAX(iID) AS max_iid, MIN(iID) AS min_iid
FROM images
WHERE userID = 4
```

PHP:

```
// Check if image is between the min/max
if($iID <= $max_iid && $iID >= $min_iid) {
    // display image

// if image id is greater than the max, display the min id
} elseif($iID > $max_iid) {
    // display min_iid image

// else display the max image id
} else {
    // display max_iid image
}
```

Comment: I havn't tried this yet because I'm at work right now. Can you explain CASE statement? I tried searching, but I couldn't find a good explanation. Thank you

Comment: does it have to be a query? Can you use min/max values can just calculate it from there?

Comment: Hmm, well what I'm trying to do is obtain images and I have set my image path names in a mysql. I wanted to click previous and next images. Do have an example for another option for this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to work this in my code. I'm still kinda new to PHP and wondering why your query is not in a mysql_query()? and how AS max_iid becomes $max_iid? Thanks!